# Como disponibilizar um download em página web tendo os arquivos em meu computador, fora do meu projeto web?

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, servlet, download

Preciso fazer uma aplicação web que o usuário faça upload de arquivos PDF e que possa baixá-los mais tarde. A parte de upload está feita, salvo os arquivos numa pasta do meu PC `/home/william/web`. Para salvar os arquivos em meu PC, editei o arquivo `server.xml` do Apache Tomcat adicionando:

```xml
<Context docBase="/home/william/web" path="/teste"/>
```

Este é o trecho de código do `index.html` onde o usuário envia os arquivos:

```html
<p>Mande seu arquivo PDF aqui:</p>
<form action="./UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="arquivo" type="file">
    <input name="Enviar" type="submit">
</form>
```

O formulário com o arquivo vai para o UploadServlet para o método doPost:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Part p = request.getPart("arquivo");
    p.write("/home/william/web/webbla" + p.getSubmittedFileName());
}
```

Agora precisaria disponibilizar os downloads para o usuário. Fiz uma página `upload.html`, lá já tentei colocar vários caminhos tentando acessar o PDF, mas não consigo. Meu projeto está dentro da pasta NetBeansProjects, que por sua vez está em `/home/william`. Os arquivos PDF estão em `/home/william/web`.

Comment: A pergunta me parece boa e estou particularmente interessado porque já esbarrei neste problema (ou algo bem parecido) no passado e não consegui resolver. Infelizmente, a sua pergunta está com 3 votos de fechamento como "*não está clara o suficiente*". Realmente eu não gostaria que sua pergunta fosse fechada, pois me parece ser uma ótima pergunta. Mas de qualquer forma, vamos ver se podemos esclarecer melhor: O seu texto não deixa muito explícito o que você quer. O seu problema é o upload que não está funcionando? Ou ele funciona e o seu único problema é que você não consegue fazer o download?

Comment: Já entendi e achei até uma solução, mas não da para postar aqui: http://www.guj.com.br/java/134723-como-retornar-um-download-por-um-servlet